# UITextView inside UIScrollView does not display long text

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITextView inside a UIScrollView. if I try to display a long text with a certain font size, the text is not showing. With shorter text or decreasing the font size the text shows up again. What am I doing wrong?

Screenshot of the autolayout here (the item selected is the textview):
[image]

Comment: Show me your code and what result you are getting

Comment: you need to increase the height of the textView as when font increases top padding increase and seems if there is no content for that small height

Comment: The `height` of the TextView should be equal to `textView.contentSize.height` to show the whole content.. To achieve this, you need to add a `height` constraint and then through code after assigning the text to TextView set the `heightConstraint.constant=textView.contentSize.height;` then `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];`it should work..

Comment: @iphonic, I tried your suggestion but it's still not working.

Comment: @Giovanni You also need to set `scrollview.contentSize = textView.frame.origin.y + textView.frame.size.height;` after you set the `heightConstraint`.

Answer (score 0):

The UITextView is inherited from UIScrollView

```
open class UITextView : UIScrollView, UITextInput, UIContentSizeCategoryAdjusting
```

So it is a bad practice to put ScrollView inside scrollView.
The reason why you don't see a long text in UITextView is that UITextView became scrollable. **Also you didn't specify your scrollView  content width so the with is calculated is  as one line of your long text.**  But you can scroll it because you will scroll scrollView. Better way is to set label inside scrollview and set the label numberOfLines = 0. Make the label bottom padding to the bottom of your scrollView and top to some items in top of label and you will get a scrollable text.

I've just understood that you don't need a scrollView to place your long text.

You can use just a UITextView for your needs.

1. Remove your scrollView.
2. Add a UITextView.
3. Set constraints as described and math them with screenshot

   - Top Space to ReadingTimeLabel
   - Align Bottom to Superview / Bottom Layout Guide
   - Leading space to Superview
   - Trailing space to Superview

[image: UITextViewConstraints]

And you will get the result like on the screenshots

Scroller top:

[image]

Scrolled bottom:

[image]

Note: You can disable UITextView editing in attribute inspector.

But if you for some reason need a scroll view:
Set constrains as described, also match them as shown on screenshots.

1. Add scrollView constraints (Superview is the view where the scrollView is placed in):
   -Top space to ReadingTimeLabel
   -Align bottom to Superview/Bottom Layout Guide
   -Align leading to Superview
   -Align trailing to Superview
2. Please a UIView inside scrollView. Use it as container.
3. Add constraints for container. (Superview is scrollView)
   -Align Leading to Superview
   -Align Trailing to Superview
   -Top Space to SuperView
   -Bottom Space to SuperView
   -Equal Width to SuperView
4. Add a UILabel inside container. (Superview is container).
5. Add constraints for UILabel.
   -Align Leading to Superview
   -Align Trailing to Superview
   -Top Space to SuperView
   -Bottom Space to SuperView
6. For the label set Lines = 0 in Attribute inspector or use the code

> label.numberOfLines = 0

[image: scrollView constraints]

[image: container constraints]

[image: label constraints]

And you will get the result like on screenshots

Scrolled top

[image: result 1]

Scroller bottom

[image: result 2]

Comment: I tried your solution, but the same behaviour happens. When the content is too long, the text just disappears and does not show anymore...

Comment: It feels like there is a limitation to the display of long text... and cannot be done with a simple uilabel or uitextview

Comment: Tried it... I am actually coming to the conclusion that when the scroll view becomes really long the text disappears because it simply cannot be rendered for memory reasons. It's a limitation, that is why all the e-readers use epub and not simple text. Let me know if you all agree. Again, all the other shorter texts are displayed properly, only the very long ones have issues.

Comment: @Giovanni, it can be only simulator problem. Try to launch the app on the real device

Comment: No, it is on the device as well. When I display a text that takes approx 2hours to read, it seems to be too much for the label or textView.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
textView.sizeToFit()
```